# Find some files by string content and upload to FTP

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Need Batch or Powershell script to find some files by its content (xls file with some string) and then upload to ftp server.

```
###########################################################

$Path = "f:/temp"
$Text = "123456"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "F:/PROFIT/INSTALL/backup/search/test.txt"

# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".txt".
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse|
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
$PathArray += $_.FullName
$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File $Results
}
}
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

#we specify the directory where all files that we want to upload  
$Dir="F:/PROFIT/INSTALL/backup/search"    

#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftp://127.0.0.1" 
$user = "ftp" 
$pass = "ftp"  

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

#list every sql server trace file 
foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.*")){ 
    "Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
 }
```

Tried this, but each time have a problem:

> Uploading test.txt... Исключение при вызове "UploadFile" с "2"
>   аргументами: "Невозможно разрешить уда ленное имя:
>   '127.0.0.1test.txt'" F:\PROFIT\INSTALL\backup\search\search.ps1:36
>   знак:5
>   +     $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: So is there a working FTP server running on your local host?  can you connect to yourself with filezilla?  are there any firewalls in place?

Comment: May be an issue with `$ftp+$item.Name` being an incorrectly joined path. What happens when you change your uri to `"$ftp/$(item.name)"`

Comment: With pure batch scripts it might be quite difficult to read and access Excel files properly...

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on concatenation of server and file name. Try Something like this :

```
#variables
$PathToSearch = "c:\temp"
$SearchText = "hello"
$Results = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$ftp = "ftp://127.0.0.1/" 
$user = "ftp" 
$pass = "ftp"

#get liste file to found with string
$PathArray=Get-ChildItem $PathToSearch -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -file | Select-String -Pattern $SearchText | get-item | select Name, FullName

Write-Host "Files founded :"
$PathArray.FullName 

#send to ftp server
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 

$PathArray | %  {
                $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$_.Name) 
                $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $_.FullName) 
                $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $Results -Append
                }

$webclient.Dispose()
```